# Rails rspec+capybara test on staging server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

So I do testing rspec+capybara on localhost, but if I wanted to test on staging server(linux), is it possible to use capybara? 
I'm guessing testing with selenium will not work on staging server.
I would like to test frontend(mostly js stuff) on staging, any recommendation would be great.

I use Rails 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the [headless gem](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless) - From the author

> I created it so I can run Selenium tests in Cucumber without any shell scripting. Even more, you can go headless only when you run tests against Selenium.

I'd imagine it would would with rspec as well.